# Disable WPF window padding

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core

```xml
<Window Title="MainWindow" Height="512" Width="512" Background="Black" Margin="0">
    <Grid Margin="0" x:Name="ABE">
        <Image x:Name="ImageViewer" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="512" Margin="0" padding="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

- `ActualWidth` property of the window is 512
- `ActualWidth` property of the Grid is 496

There is 16 unit diffrence how can I get rid of that diffence

Comment: That area is known as the _non-client region_ of your window. On non-WPF apps you manipulate its appearance using _Windows Styles_. That may give you some hints

Comment: The `Width` of a Window includes the Window's left and right borders (8px * 2, if it's not customized). The Grid is sized to the Windows's Content. There's no *difference*, you're just considering the wrong measure

Comment: If you want to modify the non client portions of the window, [`WindowChrome`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is the gap between old, traditional window bounds (location and size) and "extended frame bounds". The latter is actually visible window bounds and can be obtained by DwmGetWindowAttribute function with DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS. These two bounds match, in the case of WPF, when WindowStyle=None and AllowsTransparency=True.

As far as I know, the thickness of gap is 7px (left, right, bottom) when monitor DPI is 96 (default, 100%) and increases as monitor DPI increases. You can find a number of tips to deal with this gap by searching the above keywords.

Comment: In this case, the width of extended frame bounds is 498px under DPI 96. 2px is the window chrome which is 1px in thickness. So the thickness of gap is exactly 7px.